# Capistrano: deploy.rb file refactoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I have following code in my deploy.rb

```
namespace :app do
  desc "copies the configuration frile from ~/shared/config/*.yml to ~/config"
  task :copy_config_files,:roles => :app do
    run "cp -fv #{deploy_to}/shared/config/hoptoad.rb #{release_path}/config/initializers"
    run "cp -fv #{deploy_to}/shared/config/app_config.yml #{release_path}/config/app_config.yml"
  end
end
```

I thought it would be a good idea to keep my deploy.rb file clean and I attempted to move above code to capistrano_utilities.rb under config. I am using Rails application. And I added following line of code to deploy.rb

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../lib/capistrano_utilities")
```

Now I am getting following error.

```
undefined method `namespace' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

The value of self in the deploy.rb is Capistrano::Configuration . While the value of self in capistrano_utilities is Main. So I understand why I am getting namespace method error. What is the fix for this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `config/deploy.rb`, try `load` instead of `require`.  Also, capistrano already runs as if you're at the `RAILS_ROOT`, so there's no need to use `__FILE__`:

```
load "lib/capistrano_utilities"
```

In a capistrano config file, `load` is redefined to load another configuration file into the current configuration.  When passing a path to it, it actually calls `load_from_file` (a private method defined by capistrano) that just reads the file from disk and `instance_eval`'s it.

Comment: I though the only difference between require and load was that one of them rereads the file into memory multiple times and the other one reads only once. Can you explain why load works and require does not.

Comment: Roger, more details added about capistrano's specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Capfile on Rails.root.
if you use capistrano 3, you see this line;

`Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }`

Now, put your file on "lib/capistrano/tasks/capistrano_utilities.cap" and it will be loaded.