# require in capistrano deploy.rb cannot find file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

I have a rails 3.0.5 app and I'm setting up capistrano to use a recipe.

in my config directory I have a file named "database_capistrano.rb" and in my deploy.rb, also in config directory, I have the following line, just in the beginning:

```
require 'database_capistrano'
```

But I'm getting:

```
`require': no such file to load -- capistrano_database (LoadError)
```

Also try with:

```
require 'database_capistrano.rb'
```

And don't work...

How, in Rails 3.0.5, include files in capistrano deploy.rb??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, I manage to find out how this should be done.

Just copied the file to a new sub-directory "deploy", for organization only, and at the beginning of my deploy.rb, added:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'deploy')
```

Then, in deploy.rb, just used:

```
require 'database_capistrano'
```

Comment: Thanks, also had this problem and this solved it. Wish I understood the problem in the first place=)

Comment: Capistrano recipes want to be required. You have to add the location that you're storing the recipes in to ruby's $LOAD_PATH variable in order to get require to find it.

Comment: so is the structure app->config->deploy->database_capistrano.rb ? I'm still getting errors about not finding the file. I tried root dir, config dir, deploy dir...

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors, I got better results with the answer found in [Capistrano: deploy.rb file refactoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888670/capistrano-deploy-rb-file-refactoring)

i.e instead of `require`, use `load`. As long as that file is a gem in the bundle or a file that requires other gems that are in bundle, this will work.

To be frank, I didn't try the accepted answer, half because it looked a little workaround-ish, and half because I didnt fully understand how to adapt it for my situation

Comment: can you please add link to documentation to load method.

Comment: @ArnoldRoa I couldnt find any docs but the method is defined here in Cap 2 https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/legacy-v2/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb