# Where do I put custom capistrano recipes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm trying to manage database.yml using capistrano, following this post:

http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/06/capistrano-and-database-yml/

I'm running into trouble including the code used in the post above. I've named this file cap_database.rb but I don't where to save it, or how to load it in deploy.rb.

I've tried placing it in lib/capistrano and added it to deploy.rb with this line:

```
require 'capistrano/cap_database'
```

and then I get this:

```
$ cap deploy:db

    /home/daniel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- capistrano/cap_database (LoadError)
```

Why can't it find the file?

Comment: where have you placed `cap_database.rb` ?

Comment: @AnkitG I've tried placing it in a bunch of places:
lib/capistrano
lib/capistrano/recipes
config/recipes
config/deploy
etc.

Upon further inspection, it seems like capistrano uses its own require/load methods, and use a minimal value for load_paths (from the looks of it, it just includes the gemdir for capistrano, which is not where I want to place my own code :))

For now I've resorted to your previous suggestion, I've just included the entire script as part of deploy.rb, but this isn't a solution I'm happy with. I should be able to load files like I do in any other script.

Answer (score 0):

it's just a shot but try

```
bundle exec cap deploy:db
```

Answer (score 0):

For recipes at the gem level, put your custom recipes into `GEMDIR/CAPGEMDIR/lib/capistrano/recipes`

If you want to include additional files into your app's `deploy.rb`, then you can do it using this method:

[require in capistrano deploy.rb cannot find file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365950/require-in-capistrano-deploy-rb-cannot-find-file)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but here goes anyway.

If you store `cap_database.rb` in `config/recipes`, it can be included in `deploy.rb` using `load config/recipes/cap_database`.